# How can I insert a single page document represented by an ByteArrayOutputStream into another document?

Tags: java, pdf, pdf-generation, itext

I am at the first use of iText and I have this problem.

I have created this **stampaFattureMultiple()** method that concatenate some PDFs document retrieved inside the **ArrayList listaFatture** collection. As you can see the PDF document is stored inside the **Blob** field represented by **listaFatture.get(i).getPdf()**. Ok, this works fine and the PDFs document are correctly concatenated.

```
public void stampaFattureMultiple(ArrayList<Fattura> listaFatture) {

    ByteArrayOutputStream docPDF = null;
    ByteArrayOutputStream currentPdfBAOS = null;

    InputStream blobinstream = null;

    /** The resulting PDF file: */
    String result = "D:/XYZ/fatture-concatenate.pdf";

    // STEP 1 Creazione del documento in formato A4 e senza margini:
    com.itextpdf.text.Document document = new com.itextpdf.text.Document(com.itextpdf.text.PageSize.A4, 0, 0, 0, 0);

    try {
        // STEP 2: Make copies of PDF documents. Documents can be edited after reading and before writing them out
        //PdfCopy copy = new PdfCopy(document, pdfResult);
        docPDF = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        //PdfCopy copy = new PdfCopy(document, docPDF);

        PdfCopy copy = new PdfCopy(document, new FileOutputStream(result));



        // STEP 3:
        document.open();

        // Concatena tutti i PDF delle fatture reperite:
        for (int i = 0; i < listaFatture.size(); i++) {

            // Obtain the current Blob object representing the PDF:
            Blob currentPdfBlob = listaFatture.get(i).getPdf();

            // Put the current PDF Blob content into the current ByteArrayOutputStream:
            if(currentPdfBlob!=null){
                blobinstream = currentPdfBlob.getBinaryStream();

                int chunk = 1024;
                byte[] buffer = new byte[chunk];
                int length = -1;


                currentPdfBAOS = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

                while ((length = blobinstream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                    currentPdfBAOS.write(buffer, 0, length);
                }
                currentPdfBAOS.flush();
            }

            ByteArrayOutputStream currentFatturaTestataBasos = stampaTestataFatturaPdf(listaFatture.get(i));

            //document.newPage();


            // STEP 4: reader for the i document:
            ByteArrayInputStream currentPdfBAIS = new ByteArrayInputStream(currentPdfBAOS.toByteArray());
            PdfReader currentPdfReader = new PdfReader(currentPdfBAIS);

            PdfImportedPage page;
            PdfCopy.PageStamp stamp;

            for (int currentPageIndex = 0; currentPageIndex < currentPdfReader.getNumberOfPages(); ) {

                page = copy.getImportedPage(currentPdfReader, ++currentPageIndex);
                copy.addPage(page);
            }



        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally {
        document.close();

    }

}
```

As you can see to do this task I done in the following way:

1. I iterate on all the documents inside the **listaFatture** collection and I build the related PDF document starting from the **Blob** object:

   ```
   Blob currentPdfBlob = listaFatture.get(i).getPdf();
   ```
2. Then I create the **reader** for this documnt, by:

   ```
   PdfReader currentPdfReader = new PdfReader(currentPdfBAIS);
   ```

   and so I read this reader and I copy the page inside the document.

Ok it works fine. The problem is that before each document I have to insert a special page that is generate from this **stampaTestataFatturaPdf()** method that return a **ByteArrayOutputStream** representin a single page document.

So I have inserted this line before copy the current PDF page:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream currentFatturaTestataBasos = stampaTestataFatturaPdf(listaFatture.get(i));
```

But I have no idea about how to insert the page represented by the **currentFatturaTestataBasos** inside the document that I am generating.

Can you give me some help and some suggestions?

Tnx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have any number of `PdfReader` open. You already have one with `currentPdfReader`, just open another `PdfReader` with `new PdfReader(currentFatturaTestataBasos.toByteArray())` and add pages from one and from the other to `PdfCopy`.